# a powershell Script to generate a checksum hashes for all of my files Inside my media Folder

Tags: powershell

what I have is this Code
`Get-ChildItem "path of source" -Recurse | Get-FileHash`
what I want is
a Powershell script to
generate hashes for all of my files inside my media Folder Include files in subfolders
and then save a text file or whatever readable file that contain all of the hashes include the full path of each file
I don't want powershell to edit or write anything to media folder
Only read the hashes
im on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're almost there. All you have to do is output the result from `Get-FileHash` to a file, for which I would use `Export-Csv`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyMediaFiles' -Recurse -File | 
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\MediaHashes.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Of course, you can change the Algorithm used (in the example above I used MD5) and if you do not want a column `Algorithm` in the output, do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyMediaFiles' -Recurse -File | 
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
    Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Algorithm |
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\MediaMD5Hashes.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>The `-UseCulture` switch will have the CSV file use the field delimiter character that is set in your local machine. This is the same delimiter character Excel uses</sup>